# Resolution of overloaded extern C function with default arguments

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution, linkage, extern-c

This code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // int abs(int);

int abs(int i = 0) { return 42; }

int main() {
  return abs(1); // Returns 42
}
```

Returns `42`.

The compiler picks the overloaded C++ function. I tested this on many versions of g++/clang. Can I rely on this behaviour? Is it documented anywhere?

[Source on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XnI2jSGZymMtn7s2)

Comment: It is documented. As for reference, see this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Non-member_function_definition. (The abs can be a `std::abs` with `using std::abs;` in some implementation without side effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get undefined behavior by doing that.

> **[extern.names]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/extern.names#4) Each function signature from the C standard library declared
> with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a
> function signature with both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` linkage,
> or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

`int abs(int)` is exactly one such function signature. You tread on the standard library here, and the behavior of the program is undefined.

You may not define such an `abs` function in the global namespace.